# TypeScript Type or Interface for Normalized Data

Tags: typescript, flowtype, typescript-typings, normalizr, typescript-types

**TLDR:** How to create an interface for normalized data?

I'm building a React application using TypeScript. I use [Normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr) to normalize the data from my API calls.

To give an example from the docs, an API response like this:

Quick Start
Consider a typical blog post. The API response for a single post might look something like this:

```
{
  "id": "123",
  "author": {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Paul"
  },
  "title": "My awesome blog post",
  "comments": [
    {
      "id": "324",
      "commenter": {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Nicole"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Might be normalized to this:

```
{
  result: "123",
  entities: {
    "articles": {
      "123": {
        id: "123",
        author: "1",
        title: "My awesome blog post",
        comments: [ "324" ]
      }
    },
    "users": {
      "1": { "id": "1", "name": "Paul" },
      "2": { "id": "2", "name": "Nicole" }
    },
    "comments": {
      "324": { id: "324", "commenter": "2" }
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to create interfaces for my functions that use Normalizr. Here is what I've tried so far:

```
export interface House {
  uuid: string;
  address: string;
}

export interface Citizen {
  uuid: string;
  name: string;
}

export interface NormalizedData<T> {
  [uuid: string]: T;
}

export interface Entity<T> {
  [name: string]: NormalizedData<T>;
}

export interface NormalizerResult<T> {
  result: any;
  entities: Entity<T>;
}
```

Since I have to give a generic type T here, this approach can only handle one entity. The problem is that the entities key can have several entities of different types, eg. House and Citizen (and more). How would I account fo this? Normalizr's own types just give back `{ result: any, entities: any }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you want something like this

```
export interface NormalizerResult<T extends House | Citizen> {
  result: any;
  entities: Entity<T>;
}
```

P.S. Typescript is more useful when you 100% know the structure of response and is less useful if response is different each time. If the former is correct, then you should make types for each response e.g.

```
export interface NormalizerResultForHousesAndCitizensRequest {
  result: any;
  entities: {
    houses: NormalizedData<House>,
    citizens: NormalizedData<Citizen>,
  };
}
```

Comment: How can this be achieved if am strongly typed with no implicit any?

Comment: @iamcastelli presumably you know the types of the keys for those entities. If they're numbers, you'd want something like `result: number` or `result: number[]`